# Numpy drop duplicate rows without considering the place of row elements

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have come across many questions on removing duplicate rows but couldn't find an answer to my specific case. I have a 2D numpy array. I want to remove *duplicate* rows irrespective of the placement of elements in the row. And I want to keep the first duplicate too. Here's a simple reproducible example.

```
arr = np.array([['A', 'B'], 
               ['B', 'C'], 
               ['B', 'A']])
```

I want to have below as the output.

```
array([['A', 'B'],
       ['B', 'C']])
```

I know pandas's `df.drop_duplicates(keep='first')` but I am not sure if I could apply it here because I don't consider the order of the row elements.

What are the efficient ways to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help :  sort the array, and pull out the unique rows

```
np.unique(np.sort(arr),axis=0)
```